# Need Get to element based on consecutive object property or properties from array of object i have a value to search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const levels = [
    {
      indexId: 'A',
      level: 1,
      name: 'A',
      parent: '0',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1',
      level: 2,
      name: 'A1',
      parent: 'A',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A11',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A11',
      parent: 'A-A1',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A11-A111',
      level: 4,
      name: 'A111',
      parent: 'A-A1-A11',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A11-A112',
      level: 4,
      name: 'A112',
      parent: 'A-A1-A11',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A12',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A12',
      parent: 'A-A1',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A12-A121',
      level: 4,
      name: 'A121',
      parent: 'A-A1-A12',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A12-A121-A1211',
      level: 5,
      name: 'A1211',
      parent: 'A-A1-A12-A121',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A2',
      level: 2,
      name: 'A2',
      parent: 'A',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A2-A21',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A21',
      parent: 'A-A2',
    },

    {
      indexId: 'A-A2-A22',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A22',
      parent: 'A-A2',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A3',
      level: 2,
      name: 'A3',
      parent: 'A',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A3-A31',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A31',
      parent: 'A-A3',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A3-A32',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A32',
      parent: 'A-A3',
    },
  ]

 
  const maxLevel = levels.filter(
    l => l.level === Math.max(...levels.map(l => l.level))
  )

  const arrayStrings = []

  function stackLetter(l) {
    for (let index = 1; index <= l.length; index++) {
      arrayStrings.push(l.slice(0, index))
    }
  }

stackLetter(maxLevel[0].indexId.split('-'))
  console.log(arrayStrings)

const buildTree = arrayStrings
    .map(arr => arr.join('-'))
    .map(s => {
      return levels.filter(l => l.indexId === s)
    })

  console.log(buildTree)
```

Initially i got the longest branch with max level

```
output array = [["A"],["A-A1"],["A-A1-A12"],["A-A1-A12-A121"],["A-A1-A12-A121-A1211"]]
```

if i select indexId = 'A-A1-A12' > i get [["A"], ["A-A1"],["A-A1-A12"] ]

but expected output is code be any branch related to the node i select
it could be =

[["A"],["A-A1"],["A-A1-A12"],["A-A1-A12-A121"],["A-A1-A12-A121-A1211"]]

or
if i select 'A-A3'
it should give

[["A"],["A-A3"],["A-A3-A31"]]

or

[["A"],["A-A3"],["A-A3-A32"]]

Comment: Have you tried something yourself already concerning the selections?

Comment: Please specify more the expected output. For `'A-A3'` selection, you want `[["A"],["A-A3"],["A-A3-A31"]] or [["A"],["A-A3"],["A-A3-A32"]]`. What does *or* mean? One of them, does not matter which? The first? Both?

Comment: as A3 has two child A31 and A32 so or signifies that it can give any of them  
yes i tried but i tried using stackLetter function if i select node with index id = A-A31
i get [["A"],["A-A3"]] not the its child nodes comparing index id with indexof traversing the nodes or with parent id will give me 1 more child node but the deeper nodes as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code outputs what is required in the OP. It `reduce`s the original array, "remembering" the so-far "deepest" `id` and `level`. If for the processed `item` the `level` is not contiguous or `indexId` does not fit with the `selection` or "remembered" `id`, it is not added to the output array.

The returned branch is "depth-first", i.e. the first it finds, not necessarily the deepest one.

```js
const levels = [
    {
      indexId: 'A',
      level: 1,
      name: 'A',
      parent: '0',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1',
      level: 2,
      name: 'A1',
      parent: 'A',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A11',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A11',
      parent: 'A-A1',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A11-A111',
      level: 4,
      name: 'A111',
      parent: 'A-A1-A11',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A11-A112',
      level: 4,
      name: 'A112',
      parent: 'A-A1-A11',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A12',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A12',
      parent: 'A-A1',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A12-A121',
      level: 4,
      name: 'A121',
      parent: 'A-A1-A12',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A1-A12-A121-A1211',
      level: 5,
      name: 'A1211',
      parent: 'A-A1-A12-A121',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A2',
      level: 2,
      name: 'A2',
      parent: 'A',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A2-A21',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A21',
      parent: 'A-A2',
    },

    {
      indexId: 'A-A2-A22',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A22',
      parent: 'A-A2',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A3',
      level: 2,
      name: 'A3',
      parent: 'A',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A3-A31',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A31',
      parent: 'A-A3',
    },
    {
      indexId: 'A-A3-A32',
      level: 3,
      name: 'A32',
      parent: 'A-A3',
    },
]

// auxiliary function to compare if 1st string starts with the second one or vice versa (according to legth)
function stringMatch(s1,s2) {
   return s1.length > s2.length ? s1.startsWith(s2) : s2.startsWith(s1);
}

// main function
function extract(input,selection="") {
   var id = "", level = 0; // initial conditions, storing "last" added item data
   return input.reduce((answer,item) => { // loop the input array and reduce it ...
      // do nothing (return unchenged answer) if ... 
      if (item.level !== level + 1) return answer; // ... level is not plus one from current level
      if (!item.indexId.startsWith(id)) return answer; // ... indexId does not start with current id
      if (!stringMatch(item.indexId,selection)) return answer; // ... item.indexId does not fit selection
      // update "last" data
      level = item.level;
      id = item.indexId;
      // return updated answer
      return [...answer,id];
   },[]); // reduction starts from empty array
}

// test
console.log(extract(levels));
// [ 'A', 'A-A1', 'A-A1-A11', 'A-A1-A11-A111' ]
console.log(extract(levels,"A-A2"));
// [ 'A', 'A-A2', 'A-A2-A21' ]
console.log(extract(levels,"A-A3"));
// [ 'A', 'A-A3', 'A-A3-A31' ]
```